# Aggregating Time Series data by 15 minutes

Tags: r, time-series

I have looked at many of the questions on here that relate to aggregating time series data, but I can't seem to solve my problem. My data looks like this:

```
                    Pings Adult Entertainment Female Information Lifestyle Male MAV.TV MeTV News Pursuit Sports Young Adult
2015-01-05 07:30:00     1     0             0      0           0         0    0      0    0    0       0      0           0
2015-01-05 07:43:00     1     0             0      0           0         0    0      0    0    0       0      0           0
2015-01-05 07:44:00     1     0             0      0           0         0    0      0    0    0       0      0           0
2015-01-05 07:59:00     5     0             0      0           0         0    0      0    0    0       0      0           0
2015-01-05 08:02:00     1     0             0      0           0         0    0      0    0    0       0      0           0
2015-01-05 08:17:00     1     0             0      0           0         0    0      0    0    0       0      0           0
```

and I want to find a way to roll this up in 15 minute increments, summing every row. I've tried `merge` and `cut` and `aggregate` and `na.locf` methods, but none of them quite work. I've also tried `period.apply` but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: The `cut.POSIXt` function has the option of specifying an interval along the lines of `breaks="15 min"`.  Seems like using that approach would be close to trivial if used in combination with `aggregate`.

Comment: Yes I just figured it out, thanks BondedDust

Answer (score 0):

For `timebreak = ISOdatetime(2015, 1, 5, 7, 0, 0) + (seq(0,7)*15*60)`, 
I used `fac = cut(time(data), breaks = timebreak)` and then `aggregate(data, by  = fac, FUN = sum)`